# How to stop a php long running process?

Tags: php

If I try to exec this code, an infinite loop starts. But, ... How can I send SIGTERM signal to stop the execution?

```
<?php

$flag = false;

pcntl_signal('SIGTERM', function () use (&$flag) {
    $flag = true;
});

$shouldStop = function() use (&$flag) {
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    return $flag;
};

while (!$shouldStop($flag)) {
    sleep(1);
    echo "\n" . time();
}
```

Comment: dont you need `posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGTERM);` in there somewhere?

Comment: No: I've only this script.

Comment: `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: also its `pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, ` not `pcntl_signal('SIGTERM', `